# Char comparison in C, if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison

I'm having this problem with my code. The thing is I need to compare two chars `n` and `a[p]` but the result is always negative. This is a little quiz program for my assignment. `q[]`is an array of questions and `a[]` is an array of answers. The player enters `t` or `f` for true or false but the `if` doesn't seem to work as it always prints 'You lose!' (even if the condition is true).

```
char questions(){
const char *q [100];
q[0]= "Centipedes always have 100 feet."; //f
q[1] = "Marie Curie’s husband was called Pierre."; //t
[...]
q[99] = "";

const char *a[100];
a[0] = "f";
a[1] = "t";
[...]
a[99] = "";

char n;
int p, i;
for (i = 0; i<=7; ++i)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    p = (rand() % 18);

    printf("\n");
    printf(q[p]);
    printf("\n");

    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &n);

    if (n == a[p]){
        printf("Correct answer!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You lose!");
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (n == a[p]){` --> `if (n == *a[p]){`

Comment: Thou shall heed thy warnings.

Comment: **Note:** `fflush(stdin);` does **Not** remove extraneous characters from `stdin`. You need to manually remove any extraneous characters with something similar to `int flush=0;` then after/before reading from `stdin` a second time include `do { flush=getchar(); } while (flush != '\n');`. That will accomplish what you are **not** actually doing with `fflush(stdin);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you allocated `a` as an array of character pointers (i.e. an array of c strings) instead of an array of characters:

```
const char *a[100];
```

Try allocating an array of characters instead of an array of character pointers and initialize your values as characters instead of c strings:

- `const char *a[100];` becomes `char a[100];` - don't forget to drop the `const` since you write values to your array later on.
- `a[0] = "f";` becomes `a[0] = 'f';`

Comment: Your solution actually works with a minor fix - I had to change it from `const char *a[100];` to `char a[100];`, because when I left it `const char a[100];` the file wouldn't compile with an error 'assignment of read-only location'. When I changed it the program compiled right away. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, of course, I missed that one - sorry about that. I'll update the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is wrong. You are currently testing `char` against `char *`...

Two ways to correct :

1. declare a as an array of chars not `char *`. `char a[100];` then initialize them with `a[0]='f';`
2. or change your test to `if (n==a[p][0])` so that you test `n` against the first char of the p-th string